# How to perform an async distributed transaction among multiple SQL Server instances

Tags: c#, sql-server, distributed-transactions, saga, 2phase-commit

In the .NET ,where we have the flexibility to call multiple services at the same time with Task parallels concept. Considering a scenario where I have three different tasks , each task call different services.

For Example,

- Task 1 service  - post data in application DB
- Task 2 service - post data in centralized DB
- Task 3 service post data in Migration DB.

So assuming this three services executes in parallel, and Task 1 completed , but Task 2 services failed due some exception. so due to this I it to handled such that, task 1 should roll back the change. I need a proper solution, please let me know.

[Two-phase commit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/committing-a-transaction-in-single-phase-and-multi-phase) can possible solve this.

Comment: Distributed transaction is what you are looking for. More info https://youtu.be/k925c1WN2LA

Comment: Could you please clarify what kind of DB and ORM you use and post sample code, so I could write an answer

Comment: SQL server as a DB & Entity frame work as ORM